# Grails unit testing controller setting up params

Tags: unit-testing, grails, parameters

I have controller with following code:

```
def profile = Profile.findByProfileURL(params.profileURL)
```

and unit test like this:

```
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
@TestFor(ProfileController)
@Mock([User])
class ProfileControllerTests {

    def void testIndex() {
        mockDomain(User, [[firstname: 'Niko',...]])

        controller.params.profileURL = 'niko-klansek'

        controller.index()

        ...
    }

}
```

When I run the test I get following exception in the controller referring to :

```
No signature of method: sportboard.core.profile.Profile.methodMissing() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

So params value profileURL that I have set in the test is not visible from the controller? How can I set params for controller so it is visible?

Answer (score 1):

Exception is cryptic, but it says that your `Profile` domain class is not mocked. You should add it to `@Mock` annotation. Also, `@TestMixin` can be ommited here and you shouldn't use `mockDomain` directly in test. Just save this user instance. Altogether it should look like this:

```
@TestFor(ProfileController)
@Mock([User, Profile])
class ProfileControllerTests {
    def void testIndex() {
        def user = new User(firstName: 'Niko').save()

        controller.params.profileURL = 'niko-klansek'
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that Profile is an abstract class and then I get:
'Could not instantiate bean class [sportboard.core.profile.Profile]: Is it an abstract class?'

Comment: So mock class that extends your abstract Profile class. You can find example workaround here: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8688 .

Comment: Exactly, User extends Profile. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Although I wrote that you shouldn't directly use mockDomain, try mockDomain(Profile) in first line of your test :)